# Old Sci Fi novel about a protagonist who was cut in half, but survived and ended up commanding an ocean-faring ship that was run by a whale's brain

Tags: story-identification, novel

Back in the 80s I read a paperback I got from a used bookstore, about a protagonist who was cut in half (I think through an accident) at the beginning of the book, but survived and ended up commanding a ship that was partially made of a whale, or at least had a whale's brain.  Unfortunately this is all I can remember about it - except that the names of one or more ships in the story ended in "-maru".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"[The Godwhale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Godwhale)", by T. J. Bass, published in 1974.

> "The protagonist, Larry Dever, is gravely injured resulting in a radical surgical procedure, a hemicorporectomy, in which tissue below the waist is removed. He is outfitted with a set of intelligent mechanical legs, a "manniquin", and is placed into suspended animation until the damaged tissue can be restored. He wakes at a time when cloning technology can replace his legs, although for a price. Years before he was awakened, a clone, or "bud child", was created and is now a thriving young boy without language. Horrified by the prospect of his child being sacrificed to provide him with a new lower body, Larry opts to return to suspended animation. His child, Dim Dever, is selected by the guiding world computer, called Olga, to carry his ancient genes to a possible new colony on a planet orbiting Procyon.
>
> "Larry awakens again in a nightmare future. Far from the highly advanced past, now an enormous human population – 3.5 trillion – covers every inch of the planet in underground shaft cities. Technology and science have degraded, and all freely breeding species have been exterminated except for the five-toed neolithic humans, which are classified as a garden varmint. The 'Hive' or human population of Nebishes – four-toed humans – within its computer-supported subterranean culture ruthlessly hunts, kills, and recycles anyone who consumes their crops, the Benthic Beasts, which are five-toed humans that have formed a precarious niche in abandoned underwater rec domes.
>
> "As Larry is trying to adapt to his new life, without most of his own body or his "cyber" torso, accompanied by Big Har, a genetic defect sent for destruction as an infant but managing to escape 'tweenwalls' in the shaft city- something re-awakens an ancient, half-derelict cyborg, the Godwhale of the title. This enormous 'rake' is an ocean-going biota harvester built in part from a genetically modified blue whale. Initially attempting to rejoin human civilization, the Godwhale (named Rorqual Maru or 'Whale Ship' in Japanese), along with its class six companion cyber, Iron Trilobite, eventually teams up with a genetically modified clone of Larry, ARNOLD (Augmented Renal Nucleus of Larry Dever), Larry himself, and an assortment of misfits and refugees from the Hive. Together they set out to try to find out what mysteriously brings the marine biota back to the previously sterile oceans, while a tiny group from the Hive, the outcasts, and their cyber deities survive and thrive in the face of incredible bungling by the 'Class One' computer that manages humanity and the various castes of 'Nebish' humans brought into the fight."
>
> [image]

Comment: Ninja'd! Well done.

Comment: I checked this as the answer. Although I don't recognize most of the detail - this is too close to be wrong :) Thanx  - I'll find it and re-read!

Comment: Don't forget to use quote marks (> like this) to highlight which bits you're quoting from other sources.